# Why aren't I getting my form data object with input values in this submit listener?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have an HTML form, it's a pretty simple form, there's only 4 values that are required. It looks like this.

```js
$form.addEventListener('submit', (event) => {
  event.preventDefault()

  const formData = new FormData(event.target)
  // log our form object
  console.log(formData)
  event.target.reset()
})
```

```html
<form id="heatmap-form">
  <div class="form-row text-center">
    <div class="form-group col">
      <label for="parameter">Parameter</label>
      <span class="asterisk_input"></span>
      <select name="parameter" id="parameter" class="custom-select">
        <option selected>Select a parameter</option>
        <option value="air_temperature">Air humidity</option>
        <option value="air_pressure">Air temperature</option>
        <option value="air_humidity">Air pressure</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col">
      <label for="unit">Unit</label>
      <span class="asterisk_input"></span>
      <input name="unit" type="text" class="form-control" id="unit" placeholder="C, F, %, hPa etc" required>

    </div>
    <div class="form-group col">
      <label for="height">Height</label>
      <span class="asterisk_input"></span>
      <input name="height" type="text" class="form-control" id="height" placeholder="In CM format" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col">
      <label for="startTime">Start time</label>
      <span class="asterisk_input"></span>
      <input name="startTime" type="datetime-local" class="form-control" id="startTime" placeholder="time" required>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button id="optional-button" type="button" class="text-center my-4 btn btn-large btn-secondary">Show optional parameters</button>
  <div id="optional-form" class="hidden form-row text-center optional-form">
    <div class="form-group col-md-2">
      <label for="endTime">End Time</label>
      <input name="endTime" type="datetime-local" class="form-control" id="endTime">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-2">
      <label for="maxValue">Max value</label>
      <input name="maxValue" type="text" value=0 class="form-control" id="maxValue">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-2">
      <label for="minValue">Min value</label>
      <input name="minValue" type="text" value=0 class="form-control" id="minValue">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-2">
      <label for="frameAmount">Number of frames</label>
      <input name="frameAmount" type="text" value=10 placeholder="10" class="form-control" id="frameAmount">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-2">
      <label for="translation">Translation</label>
      <input name="translation" type="text" class="form-control" id="translation" placeholder="x">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-2">
      <label class="text-center" for="linearInterpolation">Power of linear interpolation</label>
      <input name="linearInterpolation" type="text" value=5 class="form-control" id="linearInterpolation">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-2">
      <label for="omitted">list of omitted sensors</label>
      <input name="omitted" type="text" class="form-control" id="omitted" placeholder="format eg. L4, L3, etc" value="">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="d-flex flex-row justify-content-center">
    <button id="form-submit" type="submit" class="text-center btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
  </div>
</form>

And here is my JavaScript $form.addEventListener('submit', (event) => { event.preventDefault() const formData = new FormData(event.target) // log our form object console.log(formData) event.target.reset() })
```

In my console log, why aren't I getting my form data object with properties and values on it that are set to the name value of my inputs as keys and values of the inputs as values? Instead I'm just getting an empty form data object.

Comment: Have you defined $form somewhere else?

Comment: try adding `console.log("i fired");` and see if the listener is firing at all...

Comment: Have you added the `action` attribute to the form? When the submit button is pressed then obviously you it needs some kind of url where the data is sent.

Comment: What does it log out then with current code?

Comment: The select list option values are messed up, btw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your naming convention of `$form` is common to indicate the use of jQuery. If that is the case, then you don't have a proper jQuery reference to your form and, even if you did, you aren't making a proper jQuery configuration of the event callback.

Even if you are not using jQuery, then `$form` isn't a proper reference to your form, which has an `id=heatmap-form`.

Also, you don't get your actual form field values directly from a **[`FormData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData)** object. You have to access the data with one of the many properties/methods of a `FormData` instance.

```js
let $form = document.querySelector("form");
$form.addEventListener('submit', (event) => {
  event.preventDefault()

  const formData = new FormData(event.target)
  // Loop over the key/value pairs contained in the FormData object
  // the .entries() method returns an enumerable for us to loop over
  for(var pair of formData.entries()) {
     console.log(pair[0]+ ', '+ pair[1]); // Get the key and the value
  }

  event.target.reset();
})
```

```html
<form id="heatmap-form">
  <div class="form-row text-center">
    <div class="form-group col">
      <label for="parameter">Parameter</label>
      <span class="asterisk_input"></span>
      <select name="parameter" id="parameter" class="custom-select">
          <option selected>Select a parameter</option>
          <option value="air_temperature">Air humidity</option>
          <option value="air_pressure">Air temperature</option>
          <option value="air_humidity">Air pressure</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col">
        <label for="unit">Unit</label>
        <span class="asterisk_input"></span>
        <input name="unit" type="text" class="form-control" id="unit" placeholder="C, F, %, hPa etc" required>

    </div>
    <div class="form-group col">
        <label for="height">Height</label>
        <span class="asterisk_input"></span>
        <input name="height" type="text" class="form-control" id="height" placeholder="In CM format" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col">
        <label for="startTime">Start time</label>
        <span class="asterisk_input"></span>
        <input name="startTime" type="datetime-local" class="form-control" id="startTime" placeholder="time" required>
    </div>    
  </div>
  <button id="optional-button" type="button" class="text-center my-4 btn btn-large btn-secondary">Show optional parameters</button>
  <div id="optional-form" class="hidden form-row text-center optional-form">
    <div class="form-group col-md-2">
        <label for="endTime">End Time</label>
        <input name="endTime" type="datetime-local" class="form-control" id="endTime">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-2">
        <label for="maxValue">Max value</label>
        <input name="maxValue" type="text" value=0 class="form-control" id="maxValue">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-2">
        <label for="minValue">Min value</label>
        <input name="minValue" type="text" value=0 class="form-control" id="minValue">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-2">
        <label for="frameAmount">Number of frames</label>
        <input name="frameAmount" type="text" value=10 placeholder="10" class="form-control" id="frameAmount">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-2">
        <label for="translation">Translation</label>
        <input name="translation" type="text" class="form-control" id="translation" placeholder="x">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-2">
        <label class="text-center" for="linearInterpolation">Power of linear interpolation</label>
        <input name="linearInterpolation" type="text" value=5 class="form-control" id="linearInterpolation">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-2">
        <label for="omitted">list of omitted sensors</label>
        <input name="omitted" type="text" class="form-control" id="omitted" placeholder="format eg. L4, L3, etc" value="">
    </div>   
  </div>
  <div class="d-flex flex-row justify-content-center">
    <button id="form-submit" type="submit" class="text-center btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: OP doesn't appear to be using jQuery

Comment: Don't let the $ sign trigger you. This question is not related to jQuery.

Comment: The code used by the OP is correct. The `id` on the form sets a property on the window which is accessed. As pointed out the form data is not just an object literal of key/value pairs.

Comment: @H.B. The form's `id=heatmap-form`. Where do you get that this is setting a property on `window` and is somehow being translated to `$form`?

Comment: @ScottMarcus: Look at the updated OP code, the ID matches there.

Comment: I changed the id in OP's code to at least have a chance to dive into the problem. The browser automatically creates same-name properties on window for each element with an id.

Comment: @connexo **That was a very bad edit and I've reversed it.** You can't just change the OPs code so that it corrects the fundamental problem that the OP has. You should have simply posted a comment to the OP and/or and answer, but never an edit to change the code.

Comment: Disagreed. I was expecting OP to simply have left out the code that puts the form element in $form. The problem was that OP had wrong expectations on what is in FormData.

Comment: I'd tend to agree with @connexo. As the `formData` was declared with `const` i would suspect that `$form` was not some implicit variable assignment. And the dollar is quite overused...

Comment: Also: `Instead I'm just getting an empty form data object.` clearly indicates that the code works an something is logged there.

Comment: @connexo Uh no. You should **never** alter the OPs code beyond formatting. OP says ***Instead I'm just getting an empty form data object.***, which is not what OP would get if `$form` was properly declared, OP would get a log of the `FormData` object (it's properties and methods), not an empty object. The main problem was with `$form` and secondarily, it was not interrogating the `FormData` enough. Either way, we do not ever change an OPs code like this.

Comment: @H.B. You wouldn't get an empty object if `$form` correctly referenced the form. You'd get the actual `FormData` object logged. Try it.

Comment: No, it's interpretation. "empty" just means it does not contain the expected properties and some functions instead. If $form was the issue **the code would never have executed that far**.

Comment: Well, it is interpretation, but nonetheless, a comment is what @connexo should have made, not an edit to the code.

Comment: Maybe. It's not that much of an issue, since the edit was logically sound in my opinion. Could have confirmed it with the author first, of course.

Comment: It seems to be quite a common misconception: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49470790/getting-all-form-values-and-keys-in-1-object#49470790 Also note that OP of that question states that he's getting "an empty object" instead of what he expected - which kind o empirically supports my and @H.B.'s interpretation.

Comment: @connexo That's why I closed it. ;)

Comment: Thank you so much, this has been very helpful! I actually just called it $form for syntax to indicate it's a dom element. I didn't show it but I have  selected the form element and stored it in that variable at the top of my code. What actually worked for me was `for(var pair of formData.entries()) {
    parameters[pair[0]] = pair[1]
  }` where paramaters was a created object that stored my values of my inputs

Comment: Sorry didn't realize that's EXACTLY what you suggested! haha, that's my bad thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

You want to make yourself familiar with the [FormData API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/entries). Use `formData.entries()` to access these:

```js
$form.addEventListener('submit', (event) => {
  event.preventDefault()

  const formData = new FormData(event.target)
  // log our form object
  console.log(formData.entries().next().value)
  event.target.reset()
})
```

```html
<form id="$form">

  <label for="parameter">Parameter</label>
  <span class="asterisk_input"></span>
  <select name="parameter" id="parameter" class="custom-select">
    <option selected>Select a parameter</option>
    <option value="air_temperature">Air humidity</option>
    <option value="air_pressure">Air temperature</option>
    <option value="air_humidity">Air pressure</option>
  </select>
  <button id="form-submit" type="submit" class="text-center btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: thank you for that. I thought formdata returned an object itself with my form data, but I guess I had to use .entries() method on it to get the values and then store those in an object. I used this `for(var pair of formData.entries()) {
    parameters1[pair[0]] = pair[1]
  }` . thanks!