# Getting all form values and keys in 1 object

Tags: javascript

I would like to get an object that includes all form elements which have names. So the attribute `name` should be the key and the attribute `value` should be the value.

I tried it with the following code but it returns an empty object.

```js
var form = document.getElementById('myForm');
var formData = new FormData(form);
console.log(formData);
```

```html
<form id="myForm" name="myForm">
  <div>
    <label for="username">Enter name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="username" name="username" value="My Name">
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="useracc">Enter account number:</label>
    <input type="text" id="useracc" name="useracc" value="24">
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="userfile">Upload file:</label>
    <input type="file" id="userfile" name="userfile">
  </div>
<input type="submit" value="Submit!">
</form>
```

Comment: If you loop through the entries of `formData` such as `formData.entries()` then you should be able to get all values.

Comment: First, all form field should have a `name` attribute, otherwise you are using them incorrectly. Second, please don't post your code to 3rd party sites as those links can die over time. Just insert your code, right here, in your question as a "code snippet".

Comment: Can you please explain why you consider the result you're getting *an empty object*?